# Which form of to be should be used?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. Fungi **are** a diverse and important group of microorganisms.
> 2. Fungi **is** a diverse and important group of microorganisms.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 6):

Since fungi is the plural form of fungus, **are** would be the correct usage.